# Have PhotoRec and Testdisk recover ".ts" file

Tags: ffmpeg, data-recovery, testdisk

I am using testdisk for a long time. But previously I never had .ts but now I have. So I deleted a .ts file which is not important file. After that I tried to recover any other file via testdisk (Undelete funcution) And I saw that the ".ts" file and its data is shown as 0. I am definitely sure that I did NOT overwrite any data. All files can recoverable but not .ts file.

**I just wondered** that can I recover the .ts file? I tried to recover it and It looks like a single fragment.(1,1 kB). Is there anyway to recover this file like whole movie?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu and Win8 as DualBoot and I am generally on UBUNTU

Comment: And I tried this on Ubuntu

Comment: Was the file on the same partition as either operating system?

Comment: Yes it was on the Ubuntu's Desktop.